# TableView Cell appearance issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tableVIew, where each cell is 90.0f tall (the height). my code;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90.0;
}
```

Now when i delete all the records in the table. the height of the cell shrinks to its default value which is 44 (i think).

1.) My problem is that, i need the height of the cell to remain as 90.0f even after the user deletes all the records. How can i do this programatically ?

2.) I have given 2 colours to my cell.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blackColor] ;
```

When i delete the second cell, which is black, then both the 1st and 3rd cell is white. How can i re-arrange this to be black and white in an order.

**EDIT:**

Ok this works but when i try to delete the last record in the table and `[tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows]` i end up getting Assertion failure in

`-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:961` and

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. Attempt to delete more rows than exist in section.'`

Why is this ?

CODE:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

        [self.myArray removeObjectsInArray:discardedItems ]; 

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]  withRowAnimation:YES];     

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]  withRowAnimation:YES];  

        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: You know you could use blackColor rather than writing out the RGB values for black.

Comment: there was some other colour there, i had to change it to post it to SO

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't think you can do that. One way around it would be to show x amount of blank cells to fill the page.

2) Call `[tableView reloadData]` upon cell deletion, or call [tableView reloadCellAtIndex...] on the rows before and after the deleted cell.

Answer (score 1):

If the height of your rows is really static (like you showed), consider not implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` but use the table-view's `rowHeight` property, instead.
This can be set either in code or in Interface Builder and should be the solution to your "the rows are shrinking if there are none" problem.

To your second problem:
Do you know about `-[UITableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`?

You can use this to only reload the part of your table-view that needs to be updated. It would go like this:

```
- tableView:(UITableView *)table commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)style forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
   NSArray *visibleCellPaths = [table indexPathsForVisibleRows];

   // replace this comment with whatever else needs to be done in any case...

   if (style == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      // replace this comment with the deletions of the model object

      NSUInteger affectedPathIndex = [visibleCellPaths indexOfObject:path];
      NSMakeRange updateRange = NSMakeRange(affectedPathIndex, [visibleCellPaths count] - affectedPathIndex);
      NSArray *cellPathsToReload = [visibleCellPaths subarrayWithRange:updateRange];

      // replace this comment with the bounds-checking.
      // e.g. if you only had one section and the backing store was an array, it may look like this:
      // while ([self.backingStore count] <= [[cellPathsToReload lastObject] row]) {
      //    NSUInteger remainingPathCount = [cellPathsToReload count];
      //    if (remainingPathCount) break;
      //    cellPathsToReload = [cellPathsToReload subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, remainingPathCount - 1)];
      // }

      [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:cellPathsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   }

}
```

Comment: Ok this works but when i try to delete the last record in the table and `[tableview indexPathsForVisibleRows]` i end up getting `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:961` and `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  Attempt to delete more rows than exist in section.'` Why is this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer and replaced the code with something that I've actually tested. This works well in my setting, however your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 0):

1. set the `rowHeight` property of `UITableView`.

documentation states:

> The height of each row (table cell) in the receiver.

1. please provide you data source code

Comment: I have added my code as an edit. Please look at the edit poart of the question